# Exterior derivative of $(dx^{i_1} \land ... \land dx^{i_p})$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, tensor-products, tensors, differential-forms

I am currently working on differentialforms. We introduced the exterior derivative, as follows:

> The exterior derivative is the operator $d: \Lambda^p \rightarrow \Lambda^{p+1}$ with the properties:

> $$1. \quad d( \alpha + \beta ) = d\alpha + d\beta$$
> $$2. \quad d^2 = 0$$
> $$3. \quad \text{on 0-forms}: df = \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} dx^i$$
> $$4. \quad \text{for a function $f$ and a form $\omega$}: d(f\omega) = (df) \land \omega + f d\omega$$

Now, one of the problems I have to work on is the following:

> Show that $d( dx^{i_1} \land ... \land dx^{i_p} ) = 0$.

I am afraid, that I have no clue on how to show this. Can anyone provide a hint or a solution?

Comment: Hint: $d(\alpha \wedge \beta) = d\alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^{\deg \alpha} \alpha \wedge d\beta.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot use your identity since another part of my problem demanded to prove your identity - I therefore proved your identity using the one I want to prove now.

Comment: $d( dx^{i_1} \land ... \land dx^{i_p} ) = d( 1dx^{i_1} \land ... \land dx^{i_p} ) = \sum \frac{\partial 1}{\partial x^i}dx^i\wedge dx^{i_1} \land ... \land dx^{i_p} =0\wedge dx^{i_1} \land ... \land dx^{i_p}=0$

Comment: How do you conclude that $\big( 0 \land dx^{i_1} \land ... \land dx^{i_p} \big) = 0$?

Comment: $0\wedge \omega =0\omega =0$ by definition of exterior multiplication of a form by a function, right? That is, $f(x)\wedge\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(x) dx_i=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(x)f(x) dx_i$

Comment: but shouldn't it be $d (1 dx^{i_1} \land ... \land x^{i_p} ) = \frac{\partial 1}{\partial x^i} dx^i \land dx^{i_1} \land ... \land dx^{i_p} + 1 \cdot d( dx^{i_1} \land ... \land dx^{i_p} )$? (see property 4).

Comment: Property 4 in this case just says $d\omega=d\omega$ which is true but does not get you anywhere.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. When calculating $d (1 dx^{i_1} \land ... \land dx^{i_p} )$ you were using this property, didn't you? If yes, then I do not understand your solution. If not, then how did you apply the exterior derivative to $( 1 dx^{i_1} \land ... \land dx^{i_p} )$? P.S. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: No problem! Suppose we had $\omega=fdx^{i_1} \land … \land dx^{i_p}$. Then, by definition, $d\omega=(\sum_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^i)\wedge dx^{i_1} \land … \land dx^{i_p}$ so if $f=1$ then we have $d\omega=0\wedge dx^{i_1} \land … \land dx^{i_p}.$ But now also by definition this is zero since the wedge of the zero function with any form is defined to be zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Try to proceed by induction on $p$. Start with $d(dx^i)=0$ (property 2), use this to show that for $i<j$ you get $d(x^idx^j)=dx^i\wedge dx^j$, which implies the statement for $p=2$ and so on.